# Error using Hive ODBC

Tags: hadoop, odbc, hive

I have been trying hard to run an example using Hive ODBC but unsuccessful so far.

I am running my java program from Win64 using the Hive ODBC driver from Hortonworks. I am ending up with the below error consistently.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(JdbcOdbc.java:3907)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5698)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:354)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.buildTypeInfo(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:1503)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:381)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
at inverika.training.hive.HiveODBCClient.main(HiveODBCClient.java:30)
```

What I gather from my search is that this is related to microsoft ODBC driver issue but did not find any suitable solution. Does any one have any idea about this issue? Appreciate if any one can provide pointers.

Alternately I want to try ODBC directly from my Linux VM. For thsi I need Hive ODBC for Linux Ubuntu. I am not good at compiling and generating the required libraries. If any one has done this before please share it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on your problem. Where do the error messages that you include come from? Are you using the JDBC driver or the ODBC driver?

Assuming that you're using HDP, the Linux ODBC drivers are available here:

http://hortonworks.com/download/download-archives/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using ODBC driver for Windows 64 bit provided by Hartonworks downloaded from the same link you mentioned. I am using the hive distribution from Apache directly (hive-0.9.0) running on a Linux VM. I am executing the java program from windows using the above driver and ending up with this issue. I used JDBC and Thrift from the windows and they are working fine without any issue

Comment: Are you actually calling the ODBC driver from your Java program?

Comment: Yes. I am using ODBC driver for Win64 provided by HartonWorks. I tried with the one provided by MapR as well. But having the same issue.

Comment: Have you been able to use the ODBC driver at all, say from a Windows app? What does your connection string look like?